# Javascript / Why the "else" statement still work when condition is met in the "if" statement?

Tags: javascript, ajax, for-loop, if-statement

When try to delete the location that has dependencies to it, it throw the alert message *"There's dependencie(s) to this location!"* but yet still go head and ask *"Are you sure to delete this record ?"*

Why is this?

How can I make it alert *"There's dependencie(s) to this location!"* and stop there?

```js
$('tbody').on('click', '.deleteLocationBtn', function(e){
    const selectedID = e.target.dataset.id
    let convertIDtoName;

    for (i = 0; i < arrOfLocation.length; i++) {
        if (selectedID == arrOfLocation[i].id) {
            convertIDtoName = arrOfLocation[i].name

            for (j = 0; j < arrOfDepartment.length; j++) {
                if (convertIDtoName == arrOfDepartment[j].location) {
                    alert("There's dependencie(s) to this location!")
                } else {
                    deleteLocation(selectedID)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

```js
const deleteLocation = (id)=> {
    event.preventDefault();         
    
        if (confirm('Are you sure to delete this record ?')) {            
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: `companydirectory/libs/php/deleteLocationByID.php?id=${id}`,
                success: function(data) {
                    getAllLocation()
                    $("#location_data_list").load(location.href + " #location_data_list");
                },
                error:  function(request,error) {
                    console.log(request)                                   
                }
            })
        
            $("#location_data_list").load(location.href + " #location_data_list");
        }   
}
```

Comment: Please don't make everything in your question bold. Use it only if you need to highlight parts (single words, parts of a sentence) of your question.

Comment: Your logic seems flawed as your `deleteLocation` is inside a `for` loop. You should probably declare a flag before the loop, set it inside the loop, and check for that flag after the loop to decide whether you should prompt or delete

Comment: _"...and stop there?"_ - You should be able to find a way to _break_ out of a loop or function in any documentation on `for` or `function`

Comment: It worked! All I needed to do was put the IF outside the FOR loop. Thank you all